# problem for draw polygon in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, polygon

I have a simple problem
but I dont know it reason

i did draw 2 lines between points x1-y1 and x2-y2 and

now i would like draw fill polygon between these points

this is (part of code) for that :

```
    for i in range(0, len(reverse_output), 2):
    x1, y1 = reverse_output[i]
    x2, y2 = reverse_output[i + 1]

    x1 = int(x1)
    y1 = int(y1)
    x2 = int(x2)
    y2 = int(y2)
    pts = np.array([(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x2, y2), (x1, x2)])

    color = [255, 255, 0] if i < 1 else [0, 0, 255]
    cv2.fillPoly(overlay_img, [pts], (255,0,0))
    cv2.line(overlay_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)
```

lines can draw good but when i draw polygon between these 2 lines have this problem

[image]
i like to draw this blue polygon only between 2 drawn lines
i think problem is for (pts)
but i could not solve it
any help is great
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a triangle pts should be:

```
pts = np.array([(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x1, y2)])
```

Comment: thanks , no it will not be a triangle , it has 4 points

Comment: sorry @payam I don't  understand, can you upload an image drawing where are the points you extract from reverse_output?

Comment: @payam Yes, it will be -- while there are 4 pairs of coordinates, the 2nd and 3rd entries in your code are identical: `(x2, y2)`. 3 distinct points -> triangle.

Comment: thanks carlos , but complete code is long , x1 and y1 are coordinates of start of line  and  x2 and y2 are coordinates of end of line , if you look at code , you can see  , my code can draw 2 lines if (i<1) line is blue and in other cases is red . and polygon will draw between  start point of line 1 to start point of line 2 and then  between  end point of line 1 to end point of line 2  , it will be like trapezoid or rectangle

Comment: If you have 2 lines you should have 4 points, please modify your code with all the variables needed.

Answer (score -1):

thank you all, i found the solution my self

```
pts1 = (int(reverse_output[0][0]), int(reverse_output[0][1]))
pts2 = (int(reverse_output[1][0]), int(reverse_output[1][1]))
pts3 = (int(reverse_output[2][0]), int(reverse_output[2][1]))
pts4 = (int(reverse_output[3][0]), int(reverse_output[3][1]))

pts = np.array([pts1, pts2, pt3, pts4])

cv2.fillPoly(overlay_img, [pts], (180,0,0))
```